# Django HttpResponse result outputting in console but None on site

Tags: python, django

I got three numbers, that I'm randomly outputting. Django returns me a random number just fine in console but when checking the app through browser, it's returning 'None'.

[image]

The GET is returning a 200 response, with a random value as expected but None on the site.

Any ideas?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from NumberApp import views
urlpatterns = [
path('number/', views.number),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

import random

def number(request):
    number = ['1', '2', '3',]
    random_number = print(random.choice(number))
    return HttpResponse(random_number)
```

Comment: The return value of `print` is None... Just write `random_number = random.choice(number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` returns `None`, regardless what you are priting, so you are *printing* the random choice, and then `random_number` will be assigned `None`, and then you return a HTTP response with `None`. You thus should assign the *outcome* of the random choice to `random_number` and then both print it and return it as a HTTP reponse:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import random

def number(request):
    number = ['1', '2', '3',]
    random_number = random.choice(number)
    print(random_number)
    return HttpResponse(random_number)
```

Comment: Yes, that got it working. Thank you for the clarification. Maybe for my understanding, why was the console returning a number?

Comment: @Shenzukin: it was not *returning* it, it was *printing* it.

Comment: Right, got it. Took a minute to kick in. Thank you for this.